# How to measure memory needed for a dialog box?

Tags: c++, memory

how to measure memory needed for just created a dialog box?
I have no clue at all.

Comment: This depends on tons of things, like OS, framework, and the compiler used. And does it really matter?

Comment: #BoPersson if it didn't matter why would I ask?

Comment: Because you don't understand how OS dialog boxes work.

Comment: #BartekBanachewicz it looks like it's you who doesn't understand how OS dialog boxes works.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to answer this. E.g. Microsoft Windows specifically allows a reasonable "Out Of Memory" dialog without using any memory at all (all resources are OS-allocated). But you can't tell whether other resources are similarly allocated.

Comment: surely if I create a dialog in my application, some memory must be used for it, isn't that so?

Comment: No, actually. The Out Of Memory dialog that I mentioned is a counter-example. It's memory is always in use, regardless whether you've created the dialog. That's to prevent a chicken-and-egg scenario.

Comment: but this doesn't change the fact that some memory is used for this dialog irrespective from the fact if it is preallocated or not. Some memory is used.